# How Do I Enforce Write-only Behavior to a Page in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, security, winapi, memory-management

I'm reading the documentation for the Win32 `VirtualAlloc` function, and in the protections listed, there is no `PAGE_WRITEONLY` option that would pair with the `PAGE_READONLY` option, naturally. Is there any way to obtain such support by the operating system, or will I have to implement this in software somehow, or can I use processor features that may be available for implementing such things in hardware from user code? A software implementation is undesirable for obvious performance reasons.

Now this also introduces an obvious problem: the memory cannot be read, effectively making the writes an expensive NOP sequence, so the question is whether or not I can make a page have different protections from different contexts so that from one context, the page is write-only, but from another context, the page is read-only.

Security is only one small consideration, but in principle, it is for the sake of ensuring consistency of implementation with design which has security as a benefit (no unwanted reading of what should only be written from one context and vice versa). If you only need to write to something (which is obvious in the case of e.g. the output of a procedure, a hardware send buffer [or software model thereof in RAM], etc.), then it is worthwhile to ensure it is only written, and if you only need to read something, then it is worthwhile to ensure it is only read.

Comment: As far as I am aware, at least with x86/x86-64, write-only is simply not supported. You can, however, create memory-mapped objects where one view has read-write access while another is read-only.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir shame. Guess that would have to be some kind of custom read/write protection, then, so the question of course becomes: how can I do that without adding overhead to every read/write operation?

Comment: @AMDG What on earth write-only page can be needed for?

Comment: @dimich so that memory can only be written in one context and read and/or written from another. I think an obvious application is multi-threading: create a read buffer and write buffer. From a security perspective, you want to reduce means to all but one means; for any procedure, you _never_ read the output from the procedure itself. From the perspective of parallelism, two things truly operating simultaneously cannot write to the same memory at the same time, nor write _and_ read: it's metaphysically impossible.

Comment: @AMDG What would happen to security if context can read memory which it can write to? What security or performance benefits from write-only? Or do you mean simoultaneous writes from several contexts to the same page? Probably one context couldn't read data of another context (i doubt, say hello to Meltdown) but anyway can corrupt it.

Comment: @dimich I don't quite follow what you're asking. In an ideal world, each physical address has hardware read and write independently configurable with regard to some kind of context. Suppose that while in a procedure, encrypted data remains encrypted, but in its output remains unencrypted as a low-level procedure due to hardware limitations. This is a contrived scenario, but is not impossible. Regardless, there's no point asking about particulars. The principle holds regardless. Hardware-specific exploits are not strictly relevant or in-scope here.

Comment: Write-only should exist for the same reasons that every switch block should have a power of two number of cases in proportion to the size of the input value, plus the default case. In the case of an SEU and/or system instability, the "impossible" can and will happen. More generally, the principle is to ensure that some arbitrary implementation properly conforms to some design. If you only need to read, then you should have read-only; if you only need to write, then you should have write-only.

Comment: If this was such a great idea, somebody would have thought of it already. Do you have an actual problem. Or is the answer to your question simply to note that this is impossible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Plenty of great ideas die in the mind of the one who thinks them. I do have an actual problem: it is the problem of having write-only functionality from one context for an allocated page, yet possibly read-only or read/write from a different context.

Comment: @AMDG In real world in IA-32 and x86-64 architectures page table entry has only one bit for read-write access control, thus page can be either read-write or read-only.

Comment: @dimich that's some interesting info, but it can only be modified properly through the API. My purpose in asking the question is to investigate available options for implementing write-only functionality. That certainly lets me know that the implementation currently only supports read/write or read-only for an individual page, but that makes sense given that, as stated in my question, you wouldn't be able to access it, so the writes would be in vain.

Comment: You create a "`PAGE_WRITEONLY`" page by requesting `PAGE_READWRITE` access, and then not read from that memory page. The observable effects of reading from memory and not reading from memory are indiscernible. It is not immediately clear why you'd want to enforce a restriction that's inconsequential.

Comment: It's irrational to let memory page write only but read.

Comment: "whether or not I can make a page have different protections from different contexts" If that's your question, then ask that question. Not an XY question. Create a mapping object, and map it twice, once as read-write (give that to context 1), and once as read-only (give that to context 2).

Comment: @RaymondChen My question is exactly what I asked: how do I make (enforce) write-only to a page by the operating system, and by necessity, a means to read from it elsewhere in a different context. There is no XY question here.

Comment: The x86 and x64 do not have hardware support for write-only pages. Any attempt to create such a page would require software emulation.

Comment: @RaymondChen Fair enough... then I want to know what existing facilities are available to do that, both in terms of hardware that Win32 supports, and Win32 itself. I have no reason to introduce overhead by making my own if Win32 provides that already in its memory API according to regular usage (e.g. a check somewhere in-between pointer derefs in a hardware-supported procedure callback and whatnot).

Comment: I'm not aware of any assistance here. It would be problematic to allow user mode to gain control from kernel mode (if the write occurred in kernel mode), especially since the kernel mode write could be in the context of an unrelated process.

Comment: @RaymondChen well we certainly don't want that, but we're assuming that all calls to e.g. `VirtualAlloc` are from user mode and not kernel mode like some driver component. I actually don't know much about how Win32 is designed or implemented, but suffice it to say that the question is still a general yet specific question that I'm asking here. kernel or user mode are too particular.

Comment: I'm glad to discuss more of the details of what I'm doing in particular in the C chatroom, but the details are out of scope for this question. If there were something like a handle object (purpose and performance of these is what?) or `void **` that I had which Win32 supported for checking some flag like "is write-only pointer" or "is read-only pointer" is generally what I want to know.

Comment: Existed Win32APIs don't have the function. You may need to implement by yourself.

Comment: Wait a minute... if write-only behavior is unsupported, then how is `PAGE_NOACCESS` protection implemented?

Comment: It's [`PAGE_NOACCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants#constants) when `PAGE_EXECUTE` and `PAGE_READONLY`/`PAGE_READWRITE` bits are not set.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT But how is it implemented if write-only behavior is unsupported by hardware?

Comment: All these Memory Protections(`PAGE_EXECUTE`,`PAGE_READONLY`,`PAGE_READWRITE`) are implemented by check before access but there is no write-only for page.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT sure, but the existence of `PAGE_NOACCESS` implies a means to disable reads. Yes, of course there must be some sort of check, but code is directly compiled to machine code, so where in the control flow of the program relative to, say, a `mov` for x86 NT kernel is this check performed and how? Only enough detail to determine how control flow is modified is necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Reading you comments I think you are looking for a lock system where only one thread can write or read to memory at the same time. Is that correct?

You may be looking for the [cmpxchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg) instruction which is implemented in Windows by function [InterlockedCompareExchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange), [InterlockedCompareExchange64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange64) and [InterlockedCompareExchange128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange128). This will help you compare two 32/64/128 bit values and copy a new value to  the location if they are equal. You can compare it to the following C code

```
if(a==b)
  a = c;
```

The difference between this C example and the [cmpxchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg) instruction is that [cmpxchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg) is one single instruction and the C example consist out of multiple instructions. This means the [cmpxchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg) cannot be interrupted, where the C example can be interrupted. If the C example is interrupted after the 'if' statement and before the 'set' instruction, another thread will get CPU time and can change variable 'a'. This cannot happen with [cmpxchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg).

This still causes problems if the system has multiple cores. To fix this, the [lock](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lock) prefix is used. This causes synchronization through all the CPU's. This is also used in the windows API I mentioned above, so don't worry about this.

For every piece of memory you want to lock, you create an integer. You use the [InterlockedCompareExchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange) to set this variable to '1', but only if it equals '0'. If the function returns that it didn't equal '0', you wait by calling sleep, and retry until it does. Every thread needs to set this variable to '0' when it's done using it.

Example:

```
LONG volatile lock;
int main()
{
    //init the lock
    lock = (LONG)0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &newThread, (LPVOID) i, 0, 0);


    ExitThread(0);
}

int newThread(int var) {
    //Request lock
    while (InterlockedCompareExchange((long *)&lock, 1, 0) != 0)
        Sleep(1);


    printf("Thread %x (%d) got the lock, waiting %dms seconds before releasing the lock.\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), var, var*100);

    //Do whatever you want to do
    Sleep(var * 100);

    printf("Lock released.\n");
    //unlock
    lock = (LONG)0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Threading is too particular, but thank you for your answer. As a matter of fact, I'm trying to get rid of synchronous non-deterministic multi-threading like that of Windows in preference to asynchronous deterministic parallelism with user-controlled scheduling, but that's out of scope.

Comment: @AMDG Not really sure what you mean by "user-controlled scheduling"? Do you mean that you can start multiple tasks whenever you want or do you mean you decide which thread get CPU time? The last one seems really hard to do in Windows, the first one is possible. Still, if the threads use the same memory, at a certain point they need to wait on each other, right? Maybe you can reduce the waiting by making a lock where multiple thread can have a 'read' lock OR one thread can have a 'write' lock?

Comment: I suggest we move to the C chatroom for more on this, but the latter is what I mean. I don't see it being possible to implement directly side by side with existing kernels unless I create hack patches that inject my own code at startup to allow for my threading model to work beside the existing one... which is something I'll be able to do eventually in the near future, but how to make that a secure, programmable process isn't immediately obvious. I'd rather make my own hardware, but I'm far from having such capacity.